# Planar 8-graph with 11 edges where every face is bounded by at least 5 vertices

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

The title says it all - I'm currently working my way through a book about discrete mathematics and I'm stuck on either proving or disproving the existence of a planar graph with 8 vertices and 11 edges, such that every face is bounded by at least 5 vertices. I think such a graph cannot exist, but I'm running in circles trying to find a mathematical argumentation. I'd appreciate any hints pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Euler's formula: $ v−e+f=2$, could be useful.

Comment: @M.Badaoui I already know from Euler's formula that $f=5$, but I couldn't find a contradiction so far :/

Comment: If you  combine the following you will reach a contradiction:  $f=5, v =8$, and every face is bounded by at least 5 vertices.

Comment: @M.Badaoui I think I've got it now... if every face is bounded by at least 5 vertices, it's bounded by at least 5 edges as well, which means if I sum up the number of edges bounding the faces, I've got 25, but since an edge can only be adjacent to two faces, that would require $n\geq\frac{25}2>11$ edges, which is a contradiction. (I'm just curious, is that the proof you were pointing at or do you have another approach?)

Comment: Yes this is same proof  that I have thought about.

Comment: @Sora. you should write up the proof as an answer to this question. :)